# ios: How to display "choose wireless connection" popup?

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, popup, internet-connection

If there is no internet connection and you start for example the safari app with Ipad or Iphone, a popup appears saying: "Choose wireless network"

Is there a way to force this popup to show up in my app when I want to?

The problem is, I have a button in my app which connects the user to facebook. After pressing the button the safari browser opens and shows the facebook authorization page. If there is no internet connection this popup appears, but there is no way to turn back to the app from there. So currently I check internet connection before allowing this authorization page to appear, but I also want to show this popup.

Answer (score 4):

It will show up automatically if your app tries to access internet-based resource and there's no wifi connection established but there is a wifi access point nearby.

Comment: Yes but the problem is, I have a button which connects the user to facebook. After pressing the button the safari browser opens and shows the facebook authorization page. If there is no internet connection this popup appears, but there is no way to turn back to the app from there. So currently I check internet connection before allowing this authorization page to appear, but I also want to show this popup.

Comment: Then you shouldn't just check if internet connection is available, you should check for connectivity to specific url, say, facebook.com, if you use Facebook authorization. That will also spring up the popup.

Comment: @KyrDunenkoff I am unable to get the "Choose wireless network" popup to appear.  Did this feature go away in iOS6 or 7?  If it is still available, how can I make my app present it?

Answer (score 4):

This dialog appears automatically if you have "Application uses Wi-Fi" set to YES in your ...-Info.plist and if there is no connection.

Comment: I also noticed that this dialog doesn't show possible AdHoc connections. Probably because Apple assumes AdHoc connections would be used merely for device to device connections and not for internet... AdHoc connections do appear in Wi-Fi tab of settings though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The pop-up you have seen before is in `Settings` -> `Wi-Fi` -> `Ask to Join Networks` -> `ON/OFF`

Setting this to ON allows the OS to prompt the user to join a Wi-Fi network if it finds any in reach and you are not currently connected to one.

Apps cannot show this prompt, it's a system-level prompt.