# Present wi-fi connection view within app

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080549/ios-how-to-display-choose-wireless-connection-popup), using the "Application uses wi-fi" plist key ought to make a wi-fi connection view appear when my app starts and the device is not connected to wi-fi, but I tried implementing that, and it didn't work.  Do I also have to try using the reachability code to hit some webpage in order to get the popup to appear?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779397/limit-application-capabilities-in-ios-to-only-work-with-cell-wifi-data) other answer on StackOverflow:

> Based on the documentation, setting this flag only makes sure that the device attempts to open a Wi-Fi connection. I'm not sure that it will guarantee that your networking will only occur on the Wi-Fi.
>
> There's a class out there by apple called Reachability. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html
>
> There's also a reachability class in AFNetworking 2 https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
>
> I would set your UIRequiresPersistentWiFi flag to YES and then check the reachability class that there is a wi-fi connection available. If not, show an error.

Comment: I *need* to present the wi-fi connectivty view from within my application, and that is the functionality I was trying to accomplish.  Do either of those classes provide that functionality?

Comment: @DanF: These classes can tell you about the Status of Internet connection Availability only

Answer (score 0):

I just [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24439990/118091) in the SO question you are linking to:

> This is not possible. The pop-up you have seen before is in `Settings` -> `Wi-Fi` -> `Ask to Join Networks` -> `ON/OFF`
>
> Setting this to ON allows the OS to prompt the user to join a Wi-Fi network if it finds any in reach and you are not currently connected to one.
>
> Apps cannot show this prompt, it's a system-level prompt.

Comment: But if I configure my device to prompt, and I require a wi-fi connection, that prompt will come up?

Comment: Yes, but that's your device only. You cannot force this setting on your users' devices.

Comment: Well if we pre-configure the device to have the "ask to join networks" option enabled, and then, using MDM, force the device into guided access where the user cannot even get into settings, we should be good.  I have been playing around with my iPad all morning trying to figure out what triggers the prompt, and have had very little success getting it to reliably appear.

Comment: If you have that kind of control, sure. But I thought you were asking as a developer of an app as there's no API to enable this.